# create dictionary from .h file with python

Tags: python, dictionary, header-files

I have problem in making dictionary from my header file, my header file contains this data

```c
/*Some comments*/

#define INPUT1 (17.000)
#define INPUT2 (15.000)
#define MUL (255.000)
#define SUB (2.000)
#define SUM (32.000)
```

In my python file I am accessing this from

```
read = open("example_cfg.h")
a=[]
for z in read:
    a.append( z.split(" "))
dict = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        for j in a[i]:
            dict[j] = []
    else :
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            dict[a[0][j]].append( a[i][j])
print(dict)
```

I don't have any idea what to put in `z.split()` to access my dictionary something like this: `{INPUT1 : '17', INPUT2: '15' ...}`

Comment: Using a regular expression (module "re") is easier in the long run and more reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't call anything short of a full C preprocessor implementation _reliable_. If you own this header file yourself, maybe add a comment telling people working on it in the future that these items need to stay in their current format? Otherwise you could end up with a future version saying `#define INPUT2 (INPUT1 - SUB)` or such.

Comment: ...if I wanted to build a _reliable_ solution for this, I'd have the Python program run a tiny C program that writes all the constants to stdout; that way we get the values exactly the way the C preprocessor and compiler parse and interpret them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy only "more reliable" (because e. g. the key can be easily checked to be a valid identifier) but not really reliable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Michael's comment, regex is probably the most reliable way to do this, however, there is a very simple solution to your problem (it might not generalize, tho)

```
read = open('example_cfg.h')   
a = []
for z in read:
    # this step is important, only process lines which include a #define
    if '#define' in z:
        # it is also important to strip EOL characters
        a.append(z.replace('\n','').split(' '))

# once we have the list of lists, a one liner dict comprehension can turn our list of lists into a dict
# x[2][x[2].find("(")+1:x[2].find(")")]'s only purpose is to parse the text inside the parentheses
dictionary = {x[1]:x[2][x[2].find("(")+1:x[2].find(")")] for x in a}
```